# PING domain is very slow but NSLookup is instant, website takes a long time to appear

Tags: windows-7, dns, ping, nslookup

My Internet is behaving very strangely the last few days, DNS resolution is very slow, PING domain can take a minute - sometimes the there's no delay for a period of time.

PING IP address and NSLookup is instant.  DNS servers are correct as other PCs on the same network didn't have the same problem.

I'm using Windows 7 and tried the following to no avail:

1. Disable IPv6 using the [Microsoft Fix it 50409](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852/en-us).
2. `ipconfig /flushdns`, `ipconfig /release`, `ipconfig /renew`
3. [Reset Windows host file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034/en-us).
4. Disabling all virtual network adapters.
5. CCleaner, Avast scans, Malwarebytes anti-malware.
6. Disabling Windows Firewall.

Note: The problem goes away if I boot in safe mode.

---

PING localhost as suggested by Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 takes a long time to resolve.  PING 127.0.0.1 is fine.  [My host file.](http://pastebin.com/bDxa7Wu4)

```
C:\Users\Fujitsu>ping localhost

Pinging Notebook [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

---

HDD performance monitor statistics requested by EliadTech

Physical Disk Counters

```
Counter                         Mean    Min.    Max.
-------                         ----    ----    ----
Avg. Disk Queue Length          0.037   0       0.981
Avg. Disk Read Queue Length     0.027   0       0.866
Avg. Disk Write Queue Length    0.01    0       0.282
Current Disk Queue Length       0.018   0       2
```

Physical Disk Average Second Counters

```
Counter                     Instance    Mean    Minimum Maximum
-------                     --------    ----    ------- -------
Avg. Disk sec/Read          G: C: D:    0.015   0       0.101
Avg. Disk sec/Transfer      G: C: D:    0.003   0       0.048
Avg. Disk sec/Write         G: C: D:    0.001   0       0.02
```

Comment: "The problem goes away if I boot in safe mode." Then use MSConfig to disable all 3rd party start-ups and services, and then re-enable them one at a time (and reboot) until you find the culprit.  Also, if you `ping localhost` does it resolve quickly?  Have you tried using a different DNS server, just to test?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for replying.  Ping localhost is the same - see EDIT 1 above. Previously, I've tried to set my DSL ISP's DNS servers directly instead by my router IP address but it didn't help. I've not tried other DNS Servers. I'll try your MSConfig suggestion.

Comment: @JoshuaLim Have you tried disabling the firewall?

Comment: @EliadTech Yes, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've tried MSConfig. Disabling all 3rd party startup programs (except for those that came with the laptop) don't help.

Comment: Edit your HOSTS file and put the localhost entries back in, then try the "ping localhost" again and see if it resolves any faster. Try using Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8), see if they work any better, and let us know.

Comment: If `nslookup` is fast, but resolving names elsewhere is slow, something is seriously wrong.

Comment: The name resolution goes through the following stes: 1. Hosts file 2. Local cache 3. DNS lookup. ASFAIK the utility NSLookup jumps straight to step 3. So it seems you have problems with the first two steps, which might indicate some hard drive problem. Try running chkdsk. Also, if you see any other lags related to the HD, check the response times of your HD in prefmon.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Putting `127.0.0.1 localhost` back to the HOST file and changing to Google's DNS server followed by `ipconfig /flushdns` don't help. It appears that whatever is holding it up happens before the host file and DNS server lookup.

Comment: @EliadTech CHKDSK didn't return any error. I've posted the Windows performance monitor results.

Comment: Just to let you guys know that I've also removed Bonjour as it was installed by iTune and loads into memory.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention an important point, sometimes the delay disappears when I test PING but comes back after I reboot or perhaps after sometime (this I can't confirm).

Comment: Just to be 100% clear: when you say that "ping [domain] is very slow but nslookup is instant", you *are* referring to the name lookup done by ping, not to the roundtrip statistics or reverse lookups on the responding IP address, right? There's a switch to disable the latter; I think it's `-d` on Windows, check to be sure, but you might want to try that as well. Also, please **[edit]** your post to include additional information; use comments to point previous commenters at the edit. No need to write out "edit 1...2...3..." and so on, it's all in the post history if we need the chronology.

Comment: @JoshuaLim Sorry, I meant the counters mentioned [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/02/07/measuring-disk-latency-with-windows-performance-monitor-perfmon.aspx).

Comment: A few more thoughts. Have you tested nslookup inside you LAN? is it any better? Also, when did it start? try updating drivers and BIOS.
One last thing, do you happen to have any spare parts? maybe another NIC? One last last thing, see what [sysinternals' Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) gives you, there are many things you can't see in MSConfig.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Apologies, I've tried to edit but I think I'm messing it up the more I try to edit. So I just removed "EDIT 1" and "EDIT 2". I saw others doing it and thought it's useful for adding additional info. By "ping [domain] is very slow but nslookup is instant", I'm referring to the delay immediately after issuing PING, before the 'Pinging google.com [74.125.130.101] with 32 bytes of data:' line appears. I suppose this is the name lookup. I didn't find the switch to disable statistics.

Comment: @JoshuaLim Now that I have access to a Windows box, I noticed that apparently that is Windows' ping's default behavior, and you have to explicitly turn on reverse name lookups (using `-a`) if you want that. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @EliadTech I've updated the counter statistics. The DNS slowdown was recent but I only realized it later since my 2010 laptop wasn't fast to begin left. I remembered there was a huge Windows update with 10+ items a week ago? HDD was changed less than a year ago. No change to BIOs or driver since 2 years ago. I've also tried connecting to the LAN port, same result. Autoruns gave a lot of info, not sure how to interpret? Again, I must emphasize that it's erratic - sometimes there's no delay at all. I've posted a trace of PING.EXE by HookShark here - http://postimg.org/image/t154vmu3b/

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Np. I've tested with -a, it looks the same. I've uploaded a flash video to www.fastswf.com/u7ODmQ8